# close facebook popup and reload parent window

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-login

i am using Facebook connect to log in with Facebook. That is working fine but i am using that in a popup window after the log in is completed the popup window should be closed and the main page should be reloaded but it is not happening. i have used this script to open the popup window

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
         function setPopUp(){
          window.open("sign-in.php?fbLogin=1", "loginWindow", "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1, width=400,height=400");
      }
 </script>
```

and this script to to close the window in header page and in sign in page

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
           window.location.close;
           window.opener.top.location.reload();
 </script>
```

please any one help me to do this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use just:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    opener.location.reload();
    window.close();
</script>
```

Comment: the page is reloading but how can i close the popup window. it need to closed

Comment: add window.close(); after .reload(); I use in my app: return $this->renderText('<script type="text/javascript">opener.location = "' . $url . '"; window.close();</script>'); thats the content of the page where facebook redirects authorized user back to me. works like a charm.